# How can I alter the `href` attribute of an anchor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link:

```
<a href="">MyLink</a>
```

What I need to do with jQuery to edit the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify the displayed anchor text, use `.text()`

```
$('a').text(function(_, currentText) {
    return 'Here ' + text
});
```

That would change the line into

```
<a href="">Here MyLink</a>
```

---

If you want to modify the linked href, use `.attr()`

```
$('a').attr('href', 'your new value');
```

You can use the `.attr()` the same way I demonstrated with `.text()` above (passing a function and access the current value also)

---

Ref.: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Is it not preferred to use `prop()` over `attr()` here?

Comment: @Matt: I wouldn't know why. But please let me know if I'm missing something there.

Answer (score 4):

Easy

`$('a').attr('href','yourTextHere');`

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
$("a").attr('href', 'value');
```

Might be a good idea to set an ID on the element to specifically target it:

```
$("a#id").attr('href', 'value');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
$("#id").attr("href", "Etc");
```

**[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 1):

First add a class name to that link, as shown below.

```
<a href="" class="classname">MyLink</a>
```

Then,

```
$('.classname').attr('href','insert link here');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to change the text of the link then:

```
$('a').text('My link text');
```

If it's the `href` you want to change, then, as noted by others it's:

```
$('a').attr('href','newURL');
```

If you're okay using plain JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('aElementID');
    a.innerHTML = 'My Link Text';
    a.href = 'http://new.link.com/path/to/page.html';
```

Note that you'll need some way to uniquely identify the particular `a` element you want to target, either using an `id` (to give `$('#aElementID')`) or a `class` (to give `$('a.className')`, though this will return a node list/array of elements that you'll then have to iterate through).

Answer (score 1):

you can attach it as by specifying the id to it and then uniquely accessing the anchor tag by the classname

;

```
$("a.mylink").attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

Comment: Adding a class does not guarantee unique access. You should use an `id` for that instead.